# Perl conditional extraction of lines from file

Tags: perl, grep

Could anyone suggest me a method where I could extract a few lines of text while reading it.

file sample structure:

```
A blah blah string1
B blah blah
C blah string2
D blah string3 blah
E blah blah
F blah string2
G blah string3 blah
H blah blah string1
I blah blah
J blah string2
```

Here I want to extract lines starting with string "string1" followed/ended by "string2"
In effect I want lines A-C and H-J in the above example.

My experiments are failing with the presence of line F which I would want to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Perl one liner and the [Flip-flop Operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /\bstring1\b/ .. /\bstring2\b/' file
A blah blah string1
B blah blah
C blah string2
H blah blah string1
I blah blah
J blah string2
```

`\b` in the above regex is called word boundary. It matches between a word characetr and a non word character.

From `Perl --help`

```
-n                assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
-e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as well in `awk` and `sed` by indicating the patterns between which you want to print the lines:

```
sed -n '/string1/,/string2/p' file
awk '/string1/,/string2/' file
```

In `Perl` you can say:

```
perl -e 'while (<>){print if (/string1/../string2/);}' file
```

Which is equivalent to

```
perl -ne '{print if (/string1/../string2/)}' file
      ^
```

All of them return:

```
A blah blah string1
B blah blah
C blah string2
H blah blah string1
I blah blah
J blah string2
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, I am looking for a perl equivalent for the same.